# Cron command run php script every 60 seconds and then overload everything

Tags: php, time, cron, limit, execution

I have the task in cron: every 3 hours to run php script.

I tried with WGET and PHP as well, but got the same problem. Sometimes script works more than 2 minutes, but mostly 30 seconds enough. And if execution time more than 60 seconds it get dropped (504 getway) and cron run this script again. And then again and again. Fatal overload in several hours.

I tried this with a huge amount of different syntax, but fail:

- php -q /var/www/webmy/data/www/website.com/news.php
- /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://website.com/news.php

How can I manage the command with only 1 try to run my script? I don't need it to run million times in every 60 seconds. Any limitations?

Maybe I can limit/drop execution time to 20 seconds to prevent any inappropriate script running. I just need to run script, I don't need system to wait any time, the script finishes task in any way.

Comment: fatal overload WHERE? the system running the job, or the system the job is hitting?

Comment: Post the crontab entry for the cron job, maybe a problem with your interval. Have you tried the command directly in a console? How long is the execution time in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximum execution time directly in the php script with `set_time_limit ( int $seconds );`
see more [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `wget` suggestion is a bad one. If you're going to use a PHP script for a cron task, you're better off running it as a command line script, thus running it directly and *not* through a web server.

Assuming you don't rely on server information or GET/POST variables in your script: have you tried running it once *manually*? Is anything strange happening when you do so?

A simple crontab entry like the one below will run your script only once every three hours:

```
* */3 * * * php /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: I serve it manually via SSH or directly via browser for now. It works as it should even if it needs more than 60 seconds.
The problem only if cron faced with overtime, and it run script again, but the previous run is still in the process, and after 60 seconds it hit again.

So, maximum execution time set_time_limit ( int $seconds ) is enough?

Comment: If you're running the script every three hours, I can't possibly imagine your script runs will be overlapping... But yeah, you can use `set_time_limit(60)` at the very start of your script to ensure it won't run for longer than 60 seconds.

Comment: set_time_limit(120) works fine. 120 seconds enough to finish the script.
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you want guaranteed avoiding of two scripts running in same time, you should use some kind of locking, e.g. simplest file locking with [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)